# Update Totals in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

Please take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0h0no5zy/1/)

What I'm trying to do is to calculate/update totals for each column inside a nested ng-repeat:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="cust in customers">
     <td>{{cust.name}}</td>
     <td ng-repeat="book in books">
         <p ng-init="index=getIndex(book.id, cust.id)"></p>
         <input ng-model="qtys[index].qty">
     </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>Total</td>
     <td ng-repeat="book in books">
         <input type=text value="{{sumQty(book.id)}}">
     </td>
 </tr>
```

I have 2 problems that I'm trying to solve:

1. The input boxes are now showing the correct values from my array. I'm trying to use ng-init to get the index from the array first based on the custId and bookId I pass in:

   ```
    <p ng-init="index=getIndex(book.id, cust.id)"</p>
    <input ng-model="qtys[index].qty">
   ```

   I guess I'm not sure how to correctly bind the ng-model
2. The totals are not working. But I guess I need to solve the #1 problem before I can get this to work.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Spotted some mistakes on first glance: 1.Did you assign the module name for ng-app? 2.You're missing a `>` on your paragrah line

Comment: Lihsing, thank for pointing them out. However, I don't really think they matter. I fixed both of them and the problems are still there.

Comment: 1. Please, post the relevant code in your question. 2. the input using index in its ng-model is not inside the `<p>`where this index is defined. 3. Why are you using the very, very old version 1.2.1 of angular? The current version is 1.4.6.

Comment: JB, Thanks for the comments. 1. I've included some relevant code. 2. I've tried to put it inside of <p> but still didn't work. 3. It doesn't really matter in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure if you could evaluate by doing `<input ng-model="qtys[index].qty">`. You should check out the browser console and see the error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it almost right. The problem is in your getIndex method - the return that you do there does not return from getIndex, it just exits the function that you passed to forEach. If you modify it like this, it will work

```
$scope.getIndex = function(bookId, custId) {
    var index = null;
    angular.forEach($scope.qtys , function(item, idx) {
        if (item.bookId == bookId && item.custId == custId) {
            index = idx;
        };
    });
    return index;
};
```

scope.sumQty seems unfinished (it takes a list as parameter, but you are passing an id to it). One way of fixing it would be to make it accept the id instead

```
$scope.sumQty = function(id) {
  var total=0;
  angular.forEach($scope.qtys , function(item){
      if(item.bookId == id) {
        total+= parseInt(item.qty);
      }
  });
  return total;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I can't believe I got hung up by the forEach loop. Of course, with the original code, the return statement would just exit the forEach loop but not the getIndex function. Stupid me! You're right the sumQty function was unfinished because I was still trying to figure out the 1st problem. Thank you very much for the help.